# Adding an action key to existing model permissions

Tags: permissions, liferay-6

I am trying to add a custom permission,i.e. specific to my custom model built with ServiceBuilder (see extract below from resource-actions/default.xml) . My portlet has already been deployed, and is being used.

I have two questions regarding this :

1. I assume I will have to recreate the appropriate resources in an upgrade method so that my new action key is taken into account. Is that so ?
2. If I have to add resources again to all my model instances, will the previously assigned permissions be maintained ?

Best regards,
Alain

---

extract of resource-actions default.xml file :

```
    <permissions>
        <supports>
            <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            <action-key>DELETE</action-key>
                            ...
            <action-key>NEW_CUSTOM_PERMISSION</action-key>
        </supports>
                     ...
    </permissions>
```

Comment: I'd love to help, but I really can't understand your questions. Could you try explaining your 2 questions a bit more?

Comment: I created a Project instance, and have set standard actions on it (view, delete, assign_members, ...). I now want to add a new actionKey to set recruit permission, distinct from assign_members. If I add this actionKey in resource-actions/project.xml, I see a new entry on action.RECRUIT in my role permission definitions, and I can assign the permissions to the role. I don't know if that's all I need to do (seems to work). I am not sure the resource creation (calls to ResourceLocalServiceUtil.addResources) depend on the action keys defined at the time of the call or not. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the permission system is Roles -> Action-keys -> Resources

The 'Action-keys -> Resources' is defined in your portlet's business logic, and will be carried with it in other pages or portal instances. This way you can control how the resources (page, model, service builder entities, etc), will be controlled by exposed action keys, for EVERY instance of your portlet.

The 'Roles -> Action-keys' relationship can vary for instances of the same portlet in 2 ways:

1. By assigning Roles to action keys (from the administrator's control panel), you can use entirely different roles for a specific portal where you deploy your portlet. This way, you are also defining some minimal/default permissions that will be followed in every page of that portal. For expamle, in portal P1, all users in Role R1 can perform the action A1, while in Portal P2, there is no role R1 at all
2. using the permissions table, you fine tune or override the above permissions, and give different permissions to instances that are placed in different pages of the same portal. e.g Users in role R1, in page p1 can perform an action, while on another page p2, they can't

You can imagine the action keys as an middle layer between the resources and the roles, giving you the abstraction create a great combination of role-to-resource bindings

Comment: Thanks for your answer... If I understand the logic, there is no reason to call addResources for all existing projects if I just add a new actionKey. There will just be no mapping between my new action Key and the resources or roles, so nobody (except omniadmin) will have the permissions to recruit until I assign the the action key to roles (Scope group-template or company) or until I assign the permission to specific roles for a specific instance of the entity. Is that correct ?

Comment: Almost there. the amniadmin will assign roles to action keys indeed. But the resource-actionKey mapping is done inside the portlet. the content manager will not know about resources, only actionKeys